# Implementing Mod Rewrite in Dynamic PHP website

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have built a website in PHP that takes cars from a csv file, imports them by cron into the database. The cars are displayed in a file which is **showroom.php** by **?id=slugname-from-database-row**, the slug is created on import, however I do lack the knowledge to get the rewriting to work as it seems to conflict with **news_content.php?id=slugname-from-database-row** which displays the latest news and works the exact same way as showroom.php.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Multiviews 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ news_content.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ showroom.php?id=$1 [L]
<IfModule>
```

Only page or the other works, if I comment out the above line like so in **.htaccess** the re-writing works fine on showroom.php:

```
http://127.0.0.1/showroom.php?id=604010047-honda-cr-z-3-door-15-ima-sport-hybrid-manual
```

gets rewritten to:

```
http://127.0.0.1/604010047-honda-cr-z-3-door-15-ima-sport-hybrid-manual
```

If uncomment out the above line relating to news_content.php in .htaccess the showroom.php page does not work or vice versa!

The news page works like this as above:

```
http://127.0.0.1/news_content.php?id=test-slug-news-item-from-database
```

gets rewritten to:

```
http://127.0.0.1/test-slug-news-item-from-database
```

Its driving me mad! Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

For News

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+).html$ news_content.php?id=$1 [L]
```

For Showroom

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+).htm$ showroom.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks that works! But only if I append .htm to the showroom slug, or .html to the news slug, I can get it to work now, many thanks! Now I just need to figure out a way to return a 404 if someone tries appending characters to the links like:http://127.0.0.1/604010047-honda-cr-z-3-door-15-ima-sport-hybrid-manual-append-bad-swear-words-or-characters-to-link